# vb.net and sql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have got a datagrid view which is filled by a table on my microsoft mysql database my problem is i need to select a row and its values then appear in the text boxes which i have solved. but now if any changes are to occur i want to create an update function to update the records with the changes made. I've tried but failed until now.

```
Public Sub AddMember(FirstName As String, Surname As String, Admin As Integer)
    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = _
            "UPDATE test Firstname='this should be the value entered in the text box' " & _
            "WHERE Firstname = 'this should equal to the value selected from the datagrid view'"

        MsgBox(strInsert)

        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: uuum, you're missing WHERE clause in that query. How can SQL know what particular result you want to update?

Comment: i edited the code again sorry

Answer (score 1):

I you are working with MySQL then you should be using `MySqlCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`. Also use a `MySqlConnection`. You find both in the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace.

You also will need to download and install the ["Connector/Net"](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and add a reference to `MySql.Data.dll` in your project if you have not done this already .

Also use command parameters instead of string concatenation. This is both safer (See: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and easier, as you do not have to worry about formatting strings, numbers and dates the right way for SQL.

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE tst SET FirstName=@fn, Surname=@sn WHERE Id=@id"
Using conn = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", FirstName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", Surname)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Note that the WHERE-clause should identify the database row by its primary key. In MySQL a primary key is best created as AUTO_INCREMENT column. In no case use the first name in order to identify the row, as serveral persons can have the same first name. See: [Using Primary Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html) and [SQL PRIMARY KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp).

Answer (score 0):

check syntax for update [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

so change your query as follows:

```
Dim strInsert As String = " update test Set FirstName= '" & FirstName & "'," & _
                          "Surname='" & Surname & "'," & _
                          "admin='" & Admin & "')"
```

Comment: His query would work as he posted too, he just need Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you should use.
Parameters with @ are actually values you're sending to SQL.

```
Update test Set FirstName=@FirstName where Id=@Id
```